# Standard Python Classes vs Dataclasses in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I recently began a project using SQLAlchemy, using the declarative base method to create my models. e.g.

```
from __future__ import annotations

from .db_connector import db_engine, master_session
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Computed, cast, Index, UniqueConstraint
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import TSVECTOR
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator

# Create new type for handling ts_vector columns.
class TSVector(TypeDecorator):
    impl = TSVECTOR
    cache_ok = True


base = declarative_base()


class UserModel(base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    fname = Column(String(65), nullable=False)
    lname = Column(String(65), nullable=False)
    user_name = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    user_role = Column(String(15), nullable=False)
    password = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    __ts_vector__ = Column(
        TSVector(),
        Computed(
            "to_tsvector('english', fname || ' ' || lname || ' ' || user_name || ' '|| user_role)",
            persisted=True,
        ),
    )
    __table_args__ = (
        Index("idx_user", __ts_vector__, postgresql_using="gin"),
        UniqueConstraint("user_name", name="_user_name_uc"),
    )

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"<{self.__class__.__name__}: {self.user_name}>"

    def save_to_db(self):
        master_session.add(self)
        master_session.commit()

    def delete_from_db(self):
        master_session.delete(self)
        master_session.commit()

base.metadata.create_all(db_engine)
```

I read in SQLAlchemy documentation that it is possible to do the same thing using python dataclasses and I'd like to know if there are any benefits to using the dataclass for this sort of thing as opposed to standard classes. Dataclasses are relatively new to me so I am not familiar with all their benefits save for reducing the amount of boiler plate code I would need to write myself.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not see that your code could benefit from dataclasses

Comment: @rv.kvetch when would/should they be used?

Comment: hmm, I'd probably suggest looking into dataclasses when you find you have too much code that you'd like to simplify. For example, if your class defines an `__init__` method that performs the default logic anyway, like assigning all attributes based on arguments to the method. Since you're also defining your own dunder methods like `__repr__` in this case, I'd likely say that using the `@dataclass` decorator would be a bit redundant, since you won't need to add a default repr method to the class in this case.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Thank you for the info.